# Print is not working while executing a batch file to print a file using network printer

Tags: windows, batch-file, networking, printing, command-prompt

Batch file contains the below code.

```
type "E:\Test\DotMatrix Print\DosPrint\PrintData.prn">LPT1  
del "E:\Test\DotMatrix Print\DosPrint\PrintData.prn"
```

Comment: do you have the network path to your printer? One way to print a `prn` file is like `Copy filename.prn \\computername\printersharename` .

Answer (score 0):

`Type` is used to display the contents of a file. The command to print a file via batch is `print`. If you don't specify a device, the file will be printed by your default printer.

```
print /?
Prints a text file.

PRINT [/D:device] [[drive:][path]filename[...]]

   /D:device   Specifies a print device.
```

You code should be `print "E:\Test\DotMatrix Print\DosPrint\PrintData.prn"`

Comment: `print` is for obsolete text printers.I don't think this will work.

Comment: Well you sure don't use `type` :)

Comment: @SomethingDark I want to take the print out in dotmatrix printer which is mapped to a LPT1 port.I  have searched and get a answer that to Convert  it to ascii-usa format.After i converted.it worked.But after 2 days again it is not worked.Any other Options??